# É possível remover uma diretiva dinamicamente com Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mask

Gostaria de saber se é possível remover uma diretiva de forma dinâmica com Vuejs Ex:

```
<v-text-field
  v-mask="'XX:XX'"
></v-text-field>

props: {
  mask: { type: String, default: '' }
}

computed: {
  getMask() {
    return this.mask || '';
  }
}
```

Em algum momento existe a possibilidade da propriedade `mask` vir como uma string vazia, e isso gera uma erro na diretiva `v-mask` estou utilizando o plugin `vue-the-mask`!

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trocar o componente caso não tenha uma mascara.

```html
<v-text-field
  v-if="mask"
  v-mask="'XX:XX'"
></v-text-field>
<v-text-field
  v-else
></v-text-field>
```